# Родовидовой или родо-видовой?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Как пишется это сложное прилагательное?

Встречаются  обе формы написания: в словаре на  сайте Грамота.ру написание дефисное, в другом источнике — слитное.

[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/74987/родовидовой](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/74987/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Как объяснить выбор правильной формы письма?

Comment: А почему Вы якобы новый участник, Sharon?

Comment: По недоразумению, Артем. Система ошиблась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу основания только для **дефисного** написания, поскольку это прилагательное описывает отношения (напр. связи) между раздельно существующими понятиями *вида* и *рода*, которые при объединении не образуют "гибридного" (неформальное "родовид" как украинизм от "родовод" - не в счёт). Если опираться на формальное правило:

> *Пишутся через дефис прилагательные, образованные из двух или более*
>   *основ слов, обозначающих равноправные понятия...*

https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/

Comment: Спасибо. Но вот такие проблемы. Хлебобулочный и мясо-молочный тоже обозначают равноправные понятия, но пишутся по-разному.  Как тут сделан выбор? Также надо учитывать, что через дефис обычно пишутся слова, составленные из основ прилагательных, а у нас первая основа - это основа существительного.

Comment: "Хлебобулочные изделия" или "овцебык" локализуются в одном и том же изделии (звере), а род и вид существуют раздельно, как и напр. в понятии "приходо-расходный".

Comment: То есть существует "зверь", который называется хлебобулка? Ну хорошо, на первый вопрос Иван-царевич ответил (это шутка, не обижайтесь, пожалуйста). А вот лавровишневый, хромоникелевый, они-то почему пишутся слитно?

Comment: Овцебык точно есть, не раз видел :) Лавровишня - единое растение, как и хромоникелевый сплав. Иван - вид, а царевич - род!

Comment: Да, лавровишня существует, но вот хромоникеля-то  нет. Эти элементы по отдельности добавляют в железо .

Comment: Но сплав-то существует как материал, или гора хлебобулочных изделий.

Comment: Гора? Ну ладно (к примеру, гору из мяса и молока трудно представить). Тогда последний вопрос: кобальто-никелевый сплав как пишется? Через дефис? Чем же он отличается от хромоникелевого сплава.

Comment: Здесь нужно искать истоки терминологии (если в ней есть твёрдый порядок): в ряде случаев сплав называется по металлу-основе (когда к одному металлу делается малая добавка другого), а есть сплавы, в которых степени содержания разных металлов соизмеримы.

Comment: А мне кажется, что проценты никто не считает. Скорее всего, всё дело в длине слова: при слитном написании кобальто-никелевый неудобно читается. да и вообще вся эти слова, в которых первая основа является существительным, решаются в индивидуальном порядке (по смыслу, по фонетике и т.д.) Спасибо за ответы.